# Why XDocument isn't reading elements value?

Tags: c#, linq, proj

I have code that reads `proj` files and checks for their `assembly` names.

```
XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
XDocument projDefinition = XDocument.Load(projPath);
          assemblyName = projDefinition
          .Element(msbuild + "Project")
          .Element(msbuild + "PropertyGroup")
          .Element(msbuild + "AssemblyName")
          .Value;
```

Above code works perfect in 99% of the time. Today it got `Null Object Reference Exception` when it tried to get `assembly` name from below code. The top `property group element` and `import element` are usually towards the bottom of `proj` file.

My question is why `XDocument` is not going over `Import Element` and not picking up other `propertygroup elements`?

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>


Some Elements ...

<AssemblyName>AssemblyNameGoesHere</AssemblyName>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the XML fragment you provided, I believe that the base of the issue is that your XML query is finding `<PropertyGroup>` elements that do not contain a child `<AssemblyName>` element, thus your `NULL reference exception`.  What you might be after is code to gather all the `<PropertyGroup>` elements, loop through them looking for an `<AssemblyName>` element and return the first value you find for it.

```
XNamespace msbuild = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
XDocument projDefinition = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Path\To\Project.csproj");

var propertyGroups = projDefinition.Element(msbuild + "Project")
    .Elements(msbuild + "PropertyGroup");

string assemblyNameValue = "";

foreach (XElement propertyGroup in propertyGroups)
{
    //Check if this <PropertyGroup> elements contains a <AssemblyName> element
    if (propertyGroup.Element(msbuild + "AssemblyName") != null)
    {
        assemblyNameValue = propertyGroup.Element(msbuild + "AssemblyName").Value;
        break;
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("AssemblyName: " + assemblyNameValue);
```

Comment: works perfect.  assemblyname isn't in first propertygroup always but I think that Import element was setting it off.